# Why Not Redirecting in Java Server Faces?

Tags: java, jsf-2, xhtml, javabeans, jboss6.x

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class Login {

    @EJB
    LoginManager em;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private boolean rememberme;
    private String errorMsg;

    public Login() {
        System.out.println(" In Construct " + username);
        if (username == null || username.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            System.out.println("val = " + username);
            try {
                    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("index.xhtml");
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println("--------I/O exception------");
            }
        }
    }


    // Getters & Setters ........
}
```

I want that if the username is null then it will redirect me to the **index.xhtml**  page.

It Prints the value null in console but cannot redirect me to the **index.xhtml** page.
Why ???

Comment: where is the error log??

Comment: there is no error . But still not redirecting me !

Comment: Why is this code in the constructor?

Comment: I want if the user is not login then it will redirect it to login page!

Comment: @MeAtiq where `index.xhtml` page is placed.

Comment: in WebContent folder.

Comment: Change the method name to something else like public void authenticate() and change accordingly in your button action and try again. As mentioned before its a constructor..

Comment: @MeAtiq , How about 

`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("yourWebAppName/index.jsf");`

Comment: The constructor is not really a safe place to do stuff like this. Move that logic into a method annotated with `@PostConstruct`

Comment: Still Not Working !!!